# Angular data / memory leak? Scoped services and components are not removed

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-module

I have a problem with data leaks in Angular application. Consider the following example:

In `RestrictedComponent` which is available for authenticated users only, I have defined some `SensitiveDataService` as a provider:

```
@Component({
  providers: [SensitiveDataService]
})
export class RestrictedComponent {}
```

And it **seems** to work nice - when I logout and login as another user the data in `SensitiveDataService` **seems** to be initialized again on new class instance, but... When I take a memory heap snapshot in Chrome devtools, I can actually see that there are 2 existing instances of `SensitiveDataService` keeping the whole data entire time until site close!

Here is a screenshot from memory heap at the example of `TeammatesService.teammates` field:
[image: Angular data / memory leak]
The screenshot comes from Ahead of Time production build (with turned off code uglificiation), so this is the last place where issue like that could occur...

To go further - I can see the exactly same behaviour with scoped Components - new instances are created every time when needed but old ones still live in the memory. I hope it's not desired behaviour and have seen some open issues about memory leaks in Angular repository, but I need it working now - can I achieve it without clearing whole the data manually everywhere? Maybe I can get direct access to Angular DI storage in order to delete unused instances somehow?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am facing the same problem right now..

Comment: @Mr. Muh At first we solved it by listening to logout event and cleaning all the sensitive data manually. It was a lot of additional job, so recently we decided to reload the page on logout...

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I thinky that's the safest/easiest way..

Comment: This is a known issue. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13725

Comment: I have seen this, even added a comment last year. Here I'm looking for a solution, not a description of this issue :P

Answer (score 0):

remove `providers: [SensitiveDataService]` in component.
add 
`@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
})`
 to `SensitiveDataService`